# Required output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this

```
[[{1:"one",2:"two"},{1:"one"}],[{3:"three",4:"four"},{3:"three"}]]
```

required output:

```
[{1:"one",2:"two"},{1:"one"},{3:"three",4:"four"},{3:"three"}]
```

Can someone please tell me how to proceed?

Comment: This is called flattening a list. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1. A good answer is `[item for sublist in L for item in sublist]`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list's lists to add that to another list.

```
list_1 = [[{1:"one",2:"two"},{1:"one"}],[{3:"three",4:"four"},{3:"three"}]]
list_2 = []
for list in list_1:
    for dictionary in list:
        list_2.append(dictionary)

print(list_2)  # [{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, {1: 'one'}, {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}, {3: 'three'}]
```

Comment: nope! get this as output :<type 'list'>
[{u'1': u'one', u'2': u'two'}, {u'1': u'one'}]

Comment: @ArohiGupta my mistake; I edited the answer, try again.

Comment: Any idea how do i remove the "unicode" from the output?

Comment: @ArohiGupta I don't get "unicode", maybe we're using different versions of Python. In any case, I'd recommend you to accept the answer if it solves your original question and start a new question, since this is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[{1:"one",2:"two"},{1:"one"}],[{3:"three",4:"four"},{3:"three"}]]

new_l = list(chain(*l))
```

Final Output:

```
[{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}, {1: 'one'}, {3: 'three', 4: 'four'}, {3: 'three'}]
```